# loading localized content for an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Up until now, I've generally loaded localized content by using a language code that gets sent from the browser to the server. It could be derived from the browser's language setting or selected by the user from some language selection. This could be something like "en-us" stored in a cookie or possibly a header. My server code then selects the correct language dependent content and returns that. In Javascript, I might detect the language setting when the page initially loads and then inject language dependent content into variables or directly into HTML markup.

This is the approach I've been doing for years but I'm not sure whether this is the proper approach, especially now that I have started building my apps with AngularJS. Is there a more popular approach to how localized content is injected into the response?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `angular translate`? I believe it's pretty popular and documentation is pretty decent:

http://angular-translate.github.io/